# Android banding artifact

Tags: android, bitmap, alpha-transparency

When using a dark semitransparent view, the banding over an underlying bitmap seems unmanageable. The background is just a blurred image, which I think makes more visible the artifact.
I think the image explains everything [image]

Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <View
        android:background="@drawable/blur"
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />
    <View
        android:background="#D000"
        android:id="@+id/view2"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved: On a real device, the banding artifact dissapears.